# Android Bottom Sheet Modal (Dialog) doesn't open completely

Tags: android, android-layout, material-design

I am trying to show a bottom sheet dialog in my app on a button click. But the dialog is opening partially. I would like to open the dialog completely on button click.

I have tried following code.

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    View showModalBottomSheet = findViewById(R.id.as_modal);
    showModalBottomSheet.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            //Initializing a bottom sheet
            BottomSheetDialogFragment bottomSheetDialogFragment = new CustomBottomSheetDialogFragment();

            //show it
            bottomSheetDialogFragment.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), bottomSheetDialogFragment.getTag());
        }
    });
}
}
```

**CustomBottomSheetDialogFragment.java**

```
public class CustomBottomSheetDialogFragment extends BottomSheetDialogFragment {


@Override
public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
}

private BottomSheetBehavior.BottomSheetCallback mBottomSheetBehaviorCallback = new BottomSheetBehavior.BottomSheetCallback() {

    @Override
    public void onStateChanged(@NonNull View bottomSheet, int newState) {
        if (newState == BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_HIDDEN) {
            dismiss();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onSlide(@NonNull View bottomSheet, float slideOffset) {
    }
};

@Override
public void setupDialog(Dialog dialog, int style) {
    super.setupDialog(dialog, style);
    View contentView = View.inflate(getContext(), R.layout.dialog_modal, null);
    dialog.setContentView(contentView);
    CoordinatorLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams =
            (CoordinatorLayout.LayoutParams) ((View) contentView.getParent()).getLayoutParams();
    CoordinatorLayout.Behavior behavior = layoutParams.getBehavior();
    if (behavior != null && behavior instanceof BottomSheetBehavior) {
        ((BottomSheetBehavior) behavior).setBottomSheetCallback(mBottomSheetBehaviorCallback);
    }
}
}
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/app_bar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/as_modal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:text="@string/modal" />

</android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

Here you can find the link to the project:

[Github Project Link](https://github.com/shubhambansal/BottomSheet)

Current Behaviour:

[image: Screenshot For Current Behaviour]

Answer (score 11):

At this lines in the setUpDialog method can solve the problem

```
 BottomSheetDialog d = (BottomSheetDialog) dialog;
 FrameLayout bottomSheet = (FrameLayout) d.findViewById(android.support.design.R.id.design_bottom_sheet);
 BottomSheetBehavior.from(bottomSheet).setState(BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_EXPANDED);
```

Comment: I'm not sure why it works this way, but I think it's better to point it to STATE_COLLAPSED.

Comment: Just set this to desire value: app:behavior_peekHeight="180dp"

Comment: This worked for me, however I had to use `R.id.design_bottom_sheet` instead of `android.support.design.R.id.design_bottom_sheet`.

Answer (score 3):

That method write in your CustomBottomSheetDialogFragment in onCreate method

```
getDialog().setOnShowListener(new DialogInterface.OnShowListener() {
        @Override
        public void onShow(DialogInterface dialog) {
            BottomSheetDialog d = (BottomSheetDialog) dialog;
            FrameLayout bottomSheet =  d.findViewById(R.id.design_bottom_sheet);
            CoordinatorLayout lyout = (CoordinatorLayout) bottomSheet.getParent();
            BottomSheetBehavior behavior = BottomSheetBehavior.from(bottomSheet);
            behavior.setPeekHeight(bottomSheet.getHeight());
            lyout.getParent().requestLayout();
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

The `BottomSheetDialogFragment` and `BottomSheetDialog` in Android Support Library Vesion 23.2.0 had some issues.

You can check this [doc](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library/revisions.html) in Android Support Library, revision 23.2.1 (March 2016) section.

So, the solution is to update your `com.android.support:design` version to above 23.2.0. (23.2.1、23.3.0、23.4.0 whatever the new version).

I have tested your code in the new version. It worked normally.

Hope it help.

Comment: @ShubhamBansal OK. Please accept my answer to help other guys. :)

Comment: We are already using the latest version 28.0.0. Still, this issue is happening!

Answer (score 1):

I have followed these steps, this helped me for `BottomSheetDialog dialog`.

Step1: To create a `BottomSheetBehaviour`, you need the `FrameLayout` of the dialog which exists by default.

```
FrameLayout bottomSheet = dialog.findViewById(android.support.design.R.id.design_bottom_sheet);
```

if you are using androidx, use

```
FrameLayout bottomSheet = dialog.findViewById(com.google.android.material.R.id.design_bottom_sheet);
```

Step2:
Set bottom sheet behaviour to Expanded state and also set a peek height

```
BottomSheetBehavior behavior = BottomSheetBehavior.from(bottomSheet);
behavior.setState(BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_EXPANDED);
behavior.setPeekHeight(screenHeight / 2);
behavior.setHideable(false);
```

Step3: Don't allow dialog to cancel on touch outside

```
dialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
```

Note:  You can calculate screenHeght dynamically using DisplayMetrics.

```
DisplayMetrics screenMetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
            getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(screenMetrics);
            int screenHeight = screenMetrics.heightPixels;
            int screenWidth = screenMetrics.widthPixels;
```

Answer (score 1):

add something like this to onCreateView method:

```
@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    getDialog().setOnShowListener(new DialogInterface.OnShowListener() {
        @Override
        public void onShow(DialogInterface dialog) {
            BottomSheetDialog d = (BottomSheetDialog) dialog;
            View bottomSheetInternal = d.findViewById(android.support.design.R.id.design_bottom_sheet);
            BottomSheetBehavior.from(bottomSheetInternal).setState(BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_EXPANDED);
        }
    });
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.your_bottomsheet_content_layout, container, false);
}
```

for AndroidX use

```
com.google.android.material.R.id.design_bottom_sheet
```

instead of

```
android.support.design.R.id.design_bottom_sheet
```

Answer (score 0):

Do not use fragment use BottomSheetDialog.
Sample demo uploaded to 
https://github.com/bita147/BottomSheetDialog

For Model dialog just set

```
bottomshetDialod.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
```

Works for me.

Answer (score 0):

you should set `peekHeight` for you behaviour

Comment: probably some elaboration of the answer will be appreciated

Comment: for example: `bottomSheetBehavior.setPeekHeight(size);`

Answer (score 0):

Same thing was happening with me. The weird reason behind it was `Toolbar`
If you remove the toolbar then bottomsheet will be shown on full screen.

I don't know the reason behind it. But after removing Toolbar it was working fine.
You can try that.

Comment: My guess is that it is a factor of screen height so when you remove the Toolbar there is more available space. In my case, it happens only when screen orientation is horizontal

Answer (score 0):

This code works for me.

```
override fun onCreateView(
    inflater: LayoutInflater,
    container: ViewGroup?,
    savedInstanceState: Bundle?
): View? {

    dialog!!.setOnShowListener { dialog ->
        val d = dialog as BottomSheetDialog
        val bottomSheetInternal: FrameLayout? =
            d.findViewById(com.google.android.material.R.id.design_bottom_sheet)
        BottomSheetBehavior.from(bottomSheetInternal!!).state =
            BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_EXPANDED
    }
    val view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.bottom_sheet_modal, container, false)

    return view
}
```

Comment: I forgot to say that I currently develop in kotlin.